# Salesforce flow: prior values in after update

Tags: visual-workflow, after

I would like to check if the field value is Chnaged or not? like we do in Apex Triggers.
I am able to see isChanged function in 'Before Update/Insert' scenario, but as formula fields are not available in 'Before', I am using after update flow.
But I am unable to see if the value is changed or not? Can anyone please help me with this? or if I could do that using apex then syntax or any example blog will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot react to changes in formula fields using any form of Salesforce automation, because formula fields do not have persistent values. The value of a formula field is calculated at the time of access.

Instead, you must build your automation to react to changes in the data fields that underlie the formula field. For example, if your formula is `Field_A__c + Field_B__c`, react to changes in `Field_A__c` and `Field_B__c`, provided that those fields are not also formula fields.